# use gradle sdkmanager with travis.ci

Tags: android, travis-ci

the SDK-manager seems to do the detection OK:

```
Build tools 19.1.0 missing. Downloading...
Support library repository outdated. Downloading update...
Google Play Services repository outdated. Downloading update...
```

but in the end the dependencies are still missing:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'PassAndroid'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 
    ':_withMapsNoAnalyticsForPlayDebugCompile'.
       > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+.
         Required by:
             :PassAndroid:unspecified
          > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4.
             > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://raw.github.com/ligi/ligis-mvn-repo/master/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'.
                > Could not GET 'https://raw.github.com/ligi/ligis-mvn-repo/master/com/android/support/support-v4/'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
       > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+.
         Required by:
             :PassAndroid:unspecified
          > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
             > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://raw.github.com/ligi/ligis-mvn-repo/master/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'.
                > Could not GET 'https://raw.github.com/ligi/ligis-mvn-repo/master/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
       > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77.
         Required by:
             :PassAndroid:unspecified
```

here the full output: https://travis-ci.org/ligi/PassAndroid

Comment: ever find a solution here?